# Ignore pom.xml commits when jenkins polls SCM

Tags: svn, maven, jenkins

In my build setup I have Release builds and Continuous builds (which poll scm). I use the maven-release-plugin in the pom.xml and use the goal release:prepare release:perform in the Release builds. This goal checks in the code from SVN, does the deployment and increments the artifact.version number in the pom.xml and re-commits it to SVN. Therefore, since the pom.xml was committed to SVN, and the Continuous build is polling SCM, it gets triggered  and runs the Continuous build. How can I make it NOT trigger the Continuous build when the release goal updates the pom.xml and commits it ?

Comment: Easier to disable the continuous build when you're doing a release, I reckon. How frequently do you perform a release?

Answer (score 2):

As illustrated by the question "[Run jenkins job if only SCM comment match pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037230/run-jenkins-job-if-only-scm-comment-match-pattern)", you can configure the continuous build to *run* if the commit comment *doesn't* match a certain value (like "release").

In your case, that would allow you to avoid the extra builds when releasing, providing you follow a comment convention when modifying the `pom.xml` before a release.