# Jenkins: avoid build due to commit message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to cancel or skip a job in Jenkins due to special commit-message patterns? I thought the option "Excluded Commit comments" in the job configuration does this for me out of the box, like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037230/run-jenkins-job-if-only-scm-comment-match-pattern). But no matter which regular expression i write in this field, the build is performed nevertheless.

For example: 
I want to perform the build job only if the commit message includes the expression "release". So i write the regular expression [^(?:release)] in the Excluded Commit comments field. I thought if i commit a revision with, for example "test commit" the build-job does not perform, right? Is this the right way to do when not using a post-commit hook?

Comment: Have you tried simpler expressions? Try to get any match at all that excludes no matter how simple.

Answer (score 5):

Jenkins Git plugin exposes you the environment variable `GIT_COMMIT` which of course, contains the current git commit hash.
Use [Jenkins Conditional Step] and build a step which execute the following bash shell:

```
echo "==========================="

if [ "git show $GIT_COMMIT | grep "your-pattern-here" == false  ] ; then
        echo "pattern failed";
        exit 1
else
        echo "ok"
fi

echo "==========================="
```

And mark that if the shell fails, fail the build.

Comment: I think the code above is close, but not quite right.  This is what worked for me...

`code`
if [[ $(git show $GIT_COMMIT | grep "[string to skip commit]" | wc -m) -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "skipping this commit"
        exit 0
else
        echo "ok to build"
fi
`code`

Answer (score 4):

Late reply but may help some one in future,
There is a plugin to skip build depending on git commit message, just include a [ci-skip] in the commit message junkin will skip the build

[jenkins-ci-skip-plugin](https://github.com/banyan/jenkins-ci-skip-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

To trigger builds only for commits with "release" word (case-insensitive) set this in the "Excluded Commit comments" field in job configuration:

```
(?i)(?s)(?!.*\brelease\b.*)^.*$
```

Better still, use a trigger phrase which is unlikely to be added to a commit message accidentally. For example, use "[ci build]":

```
(?i)(?s)(?!.*\[ci build\].*)^.*$
```

#### How does this work?

- `(?i)` tells regex do do case-insensitive match. This is optional, but useful if you want to match "Release" and "RELEASE" as well as "release".
- `(?s)` makes dot to match line-ends (aka *dotall* option), so that we look for matches within the entire commit message. By default dot doesn't match line-ends, so if there is no "release" keyword on one of the lines in the commit message, the pattern would match on that line, and commit would be incorrectly ignored by Jenkins. With dotall, we look at the entire commit message, ignoring any line ends.
- `(?!.*\brelease\b.*)` - negative look-ahead pattern. Any match is discarded if this pattern is found within it. In this pattern:

  - `.*` matches anything before our trigger phrase and after it. We need this because of the way java regex matching works (quote from the [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)):

> myString.matches("regex") returns true or false depending whether the string can be matched entirely by the regular expression. It is important to remember that String.matches() only returns true if the entire string can be matched. In other words: "regex" is applied as if you had written "^regex$" with start and end of string anchors. This is different from most other regex libraries, where the "quick match test" method returns true if the regex can be matched anywhere in the string. If myString is abc then myString.matches("bc") returns false. bc matches abc, but ^bc$ (which is really being used here) does not.

- `\b` makes sure that there is a word boundary before and after the keyword, as you probably don't want to match "unreleased" etc.
- `^.*$` is the actual matching pattern we are looking for. Note that ^ and $ match start of the *string* and end of the *string*, not the start/end of *lines* within that string. This is default behavior for java regex, unless multi-line mode is enabled. In other words, this pattern matches the entire commit message, because dotall mode was enabled by `(?s)` and dot matches newlines.

So matching algorithm would match the entire commit message, and then discard it or not depending on whether it finds negative look-ahead pattern anywhere in it.

#### Why your expression didn't work?

There were two problems with your suggested regex expression. First, you used incorrect regex syntax for excluding a pattern. Second, you didn't tell what your pattern should *include*, only what it should exclude. Therefore it would never match anything even if you used correct syntax. And because it doesn't match anything, then nothing is excluded from triggering jobs, i.e. any commits would trigger.

#### References

If you need more information, look for [java.util.regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) package which is used by Jenkins uses for matching. I used [this online java regex tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html) to test my expressions. I've also found a nice [tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) - learned about `(?m)`, `(?s)` and `(?i)` there.